# Is it possible to change the css of one cell in a p:panelGrid

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to change the css of a basic panelgrid.

Basically I want the text of the right column on the right. This doesn't work

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2" style="height: 220px;width:100%;">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Car" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="Colour:" />
    <h:outputText style="text-align: right;" value="blue" />
    <h:outputText value="Brand:" />
    <h:outputText style="text-align: right;" value="Ferrari" />
</p:panelGrid>
```

Is there any way to change it ?

Comment: Use th:lastchild - use info about it on google(search firstchild too) to understand how it works

Comment: thanks it's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: my pleasure buddy ;)